# ajaxSetup (beforeSend not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, header

after login to remote aPI server, and getting an access_token, I try to set the authorization header for all subsequent ajax calls :

```
      .done(function (result) {
         console.log("GOT AUTHORIZATION");
         amplify.store( "tokens", { access_token: result.access_token, refresh_token: result.refresh_token, token_type: result.token_type, expires_in: result.expires_in });
         var authorization = 'Bearer ' + amplify.store( "tokens" ).access_token;
         console.log(authorization);

         $.ajaxSetup({
             beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);
             }
         });
```

on console I can see :

```
GOT AUTHORIZATION login.js:34
Bearer 6b7578772fbb4178793100651f2234de840237fe
```

but none of subsequent ajax calls get the correct header set :

```
https://macmini.local:8000/Categories?_=1381758170726
```

cannot succeed as no access_token is found in the header ( server console ..)

```
{ code: 400,
   error: 'invalid_request',
   error_description: 'The access token was not found',stack: undefined }
saveAccessToken: 6b7578772fbb4178793100651f2234de840237fe, client_id: 1234567890, user_id: 1
```

I tried to modify the header inside the ajax call wo any success

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Updated Answer

*As of jQuery 1.5 `.ajax` supports `headers` property*

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorization
    }
})
.done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
});
```

*Notes: the `authorization` variable should be set somewhere before this call*

---

## Old Answer

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);
             }
    });
});
```

For the `ajaxSetup` to work you need to call it in the document.ready.

Comment: Thanks ... it's working this way... I found also how to make the beforeSend working inside the ajax call block...
I forgot to add :   async:false  ..

                    $.ajax( 'https://macMini.local:8000/Categories', {
                     type: "GET",
                     cache: false,
                        async: false,
                     dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings){ 
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + amplify.store( "tokens" ).access_token); 
                        }
                    })

Comment: this is probably outdated now you can just set "headers" property directly in $.ajax()

Comment: @MonoThreaded updated answer, thanks for point this out to me.  Without you I wouldn't notice this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came here from Google and thought other people searching the same thing should have a working solution. I have tried the suggested answer but it does not work for me.

A solution which solved my problem is to set header directly in `xhr` object inside of [`$.ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/):

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(ev, xhr, settings) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)}`);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Marketplace', localStorage.getItem('marketplace'));
});
```

You should call it in the `document.ready` for the `ajaxSend` to work.

That similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166395/1335142) helped me.