# beforeSend in $.ajaxSetup + beforeSend in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

To solve the CSRF problem, I use a client-side setup for Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

Until today, everything worked fine. 
But now I need to do some check before post:

```
var check;
//...
$.ajax({
    //...
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        if (check == 1){
            xhr.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function(data){
        //...
    }
});
```

Have CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
As I understand it, I just cancel the action of ajaxSetup for the new function. 
How to combine these two things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$(document).ajaxSend(function(ev, jqhr, settings) { ... })` instead of `.ajaxSetup`.

As you said `.ajaxSetup` defines a default handler which then can be overriden. With `.ajaxSend` you can register multiple handlers to fire before an ajax request is sent. Works fine with custom `beforeSend` handler.